# Lognormal pdf generates zero in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to generate random numbers from lognormal distribution on background of exponential distribution as folows:

I have 100 integers (say localities) from 1 to 25. This integers are generated from my own exponential-like distribution.

On this localities I want to distribute N items.  But these items have their own lognormal distribution, with some mode (between 1 and 25) and standart deviation (from 1 to 7). My code works like this:

I have array of localities called `variable_vec`, I know N called `N`, I know mode called `pref_value` and I know standard deviation called `power_of_preference`.

First I will compute `shape` and `scale` parameters from `pref_value` and `power_of_preference`. Than my progress is as folows:

```
unique_localities = np.unique(np.array(vec_of_variable)) #all values of localities
res1 = [0 for i in range(len(unique_localities))]
res = [0 for i in range(len(vec_of_variable))] #this will be desired output
for i in range(len(res1)):
    res1[i] = stats.lognorm.pdf(unique_localities[i], shape, 0, scale) #pdfs of values of localities
res1 = np.array([x/min(res1) for x in res1]) #here is the problem, min(res1) could be zero, see text
res1 = np.round(res1)
res1 = np.cumsum(res1)
item = 0
while item < N:
    r = random.uniform(0, max(res1))
    site_pdf_value_vec = [x for x in res1 if x >= r]
    site_pdf_value = min(site_pdf_value_vec) #this is value of locality where Ill place one item
```

The code continues but crucial part is here. Simply, lognorm pdf values of localities are 'probabilities' that Ill place my item in that locality. This is why I need pdf values.

PS: This approach is approved by my supervisor so I do not want to change it.

The problem is, that sometimes happens, that `min(res1) = 0`. Than ill divide by zero, and `res1` become array of infinities. The lognormal for `x` between 0 and 25 is never zero, but it could be very close. I thing that problem is that one of these pdf values is too close to zero, so python will `round` it to zero.

My question is, how to avoid getting zeros in `res1` in my code? My idea was to replace zeros by smallest positive floats in python, but I dont know this value. Or is there another, more elegant solution?

Thx for help.

PS: Someone could thing about not taking reverse values of `res1`, the problem step looks superflows. But it is the control, that min of these values is not zero. In another words, every locality must have some "interval" 'probability' that ill place item in it, if one pdf is zero, its probability is not interval but one number.

Answer (score 2):

Compute `lognorm.logpdf` rather than `lognorm.pdf`, and then work in log space. This should have better accuracy for the very small probabilities that are being rounded to zero.

Comment: I tried this solution but problem still sometimes occur. But thank you. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: You mean the log is -inf? In that case you should treat the probability as actually zero, and if your algorithm has you dividing by zero, it's an issue with the algorithm rather than the code.